# Is it possible to use the second argument of Dynamic when the first argument is a list?

Tags: dynamic, locator

I want to make a `LocatorPane` which allows the user to move the locators, with the restriction that the locators can only be moved to integer coordinates. However, I cannot figure out how to use the second argument of `Dynamic` when the first argument is a list of points. Is there some specific syntax that I use in the second argument to refer to the part of the list corresponding to the locator currently being moved? And in the pure function, will `#` only refer to the new value of the locator currently being moved, or the new value of the whole list of points? Sorry if this is a dumb question/has been asked before, I am new to Mathematica (and programming in general) and have been searching for hours for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` refers to the whole list of point. Here is a different example, that shows how the second argument of `Dynamic` can be used inside a `LocatorPane` with multiple `Locator`s:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 1}/2, {-1, 1}/2, {1, -1}/2}}, 
  {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = Normalize /@ #) &], Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}], 
   LocatorAutoCreate -> True], Dynamic[pt]}]
```

If you only want to restrict the last `Locator` (the latest one added to the list):

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 1}/2, {-1, 1}/2, {1, -1}/2}},
 {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = #; pt[[-1]] = Normalize[Last@#]) &], 
   Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}], LocatorAutoCreate -> True], Dynamic[pt]}]
```

One could also just restrict the movement of the `Locator` that is currently being moved, but that requires saving the last state in an additional variable and checking which point actually changed, which makes it more complicated:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 1}/2, {-1, 1}/2, {1, -1}/2}, npt, p, nr},
 {LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[pt, (npt = #; 
      nr = First@Pick[Range@Length[npt], UnitStep /@ -Abs[pt - npt], {0, 0}]; 
      pt[[nr]] = Normalize[npt[[nr]]]) &], 
   Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}], LocatorAutoCreate -> True], Dynamic[pt]}]
```